# Change foreach to show only first/last added image

Tags: php, foreach

I have following code construction. It gives out an image of the product, which was even added to the shopping card. Images appear in the adding order: the image on top is the image, which was added last.

How can i change this code so, that i get showing only one image, from recently added product (but not all images from all added products)? I guess, i need change something in  *foreach ($items as $item)* so, that the image is showing not for each $item, but only for one $item, but don't know how to modify this code exactly...

Thanks for your help and advises!

Here is the code:

```
<table>
    <?php $i=0; $k=0; $subtotal = 0;?>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>

    <?php
        $link = K2StoreItem::getK2Link($item->product_id);
        $link = JRoute::_($link);
        $image_path = K2StoreItem::getK2Image($item->product_id, $this->params);
    ?>
    <tr class="row<?php echo $k; ?>">
        <?php if($this->params->get('show_thumb_cart')) : ?>
        <td class="warkorb2">
            <?php if(!empty($image_path)) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" class="itemImg<?php echo $this->params->get('cartimage_size','small') ?>" />
            <?php endif;?>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php ++$i; $k = (1 - $k); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<table>
```

Comment: why do you close sections of PHP then immediately start a new PHP section?

Comment: you are right. I just copied the code part from the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Query with a limit or do something like this

```
<?php $lastItem = end($items) ?> <!-- return the last item in the $items array -->
<?php
    $link = K2StoreItem::getK2Link($lastItem->product_id);
    $link = JRoute::_($link);
    $image_path = K2StoreItem::getK2Image($lastItem->product_id, $this->params);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works nearly like it must - shows always only the first added image

Comment: If i change end($items) to current($items), it shows always the second added

Answer (score 0):

in the query that you did not post you can do a LIMIT 0,1 and also add in a SORT BY .. be it id, time etc..